# Finding edge cases and solving for circular queues and circular permutations

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a circular queue for example {1,2,3,4,5,6}
Now a pattern is given to me so i have to find if its split from the circular queue.
For example if i'm given a pattern such as {4,5,6,1,2,3} then yes its split from the circular queue.

If i'm given another patter such as {4,3,2,1,6,5} then yes it's split from the circular queue.Here i have displayed the two possible test cases that i can think of.

Another example would be if i'm given a {4,5,6,2,3,4} or {7,6,5,3,4,5} which are both not split from the circular queue.

Just wanted to if any one can find any more possible test cases for this problem.

Comment: A "no, it's not a split" example might be helpful

Comment: Don't understand much, you should show the code tried

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem, and you're even straight out asking for an algorithm to solve it. Why don't you try coding something out and posting it? Let's see how far you've gotten, and we'll take it from there.

Comment: OP is asking for corner cases in a circular queue. Surely such a structure has no corners ?

Answer (score 0):

Having a pattern "split from a circular queue" is not standard terminology, but supposing that you mean there is a sequence of entries in the queue matching the pattern, here are three more cases to try:
• Any queue, empty pattern – should match
• Empty queue, not-empty pattern – should not match
• With queue={1,2,3}, pattern {1,2,3,1,2} – should match